# Angular : Why my controller is not executed

Tags: angularjs, controller, execute

Here my code :-

```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
      <label>Type d'objets à importer
        <select>
          <option value="categorie">Catégories de mot clé</option>
          <option value="categorie">Mots clés</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>Déposer un array au format JSON<br>
        <textarea ng-model="array"></textarea>
      </label>
      <button ng-click="import()">Importer</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/csp/libraries/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

    (function() {

        angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('MainController', MainController);

        console.log('writed in the console');
        function MainController($scope) {
            console.log('never writed in the console');
            $scope.array = [];

            $scope.import = function() {
                console.log($scope.array);
            };
        }
      })();
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I write somthing at load, but the sentense inside the controller is never loaded.
I haven't any errors in the console and angular is correctly loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined the controller in your html.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call controller name in `ng-controller` where ever you required,
Add **`ng-controller='MainController'`** on the `<div>` where you want to call controller or where you have to apply business logic.
But always call `ng-controller` after your app started.

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="MainController" class="container">

     // write HTML code

   </div>
</body>
```